# Adding Curl Feature to Swagger-UI

Tags: curl, swagger, swagger-ui

I have been using Swagger-UI to document my APIs and have been loving it, however I was wondering if in the "try it now" section (when Swagger returns the request URL, if there was a way to also show the CURL?

I was wondering if someone had devised a hack to inject this into the prebuilt Swagger-UI format (as I just generated it using a Swagger-Spec).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333839/adding-curl-feature-to-swagger-ui and https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/3e498a5d0b0d7fc493f01eed2371c4fed8019813/lib/types/operation.js#L780

Comment: Sorry did you mean to link me to a different stackoverflow question?

Comment: Huh. Yeah, sorry, the copy didn't work ;) Meant - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1073

Comment: Is there a specific piece of code for the curl itself? I seem to recall stumbling across something in the swagger js files but can't find it

Comment: You mean the second link provided in the first comment?

Comment: Could you post the link you mean? I am having difficulties finding the line of code that I remember seeing and am wondering if you are talking about the same thing

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/blob/3e498a5d0b0d7fc493f01eed2371c4fed8019813/lib/types/operation.js#L780

Comment: Do you know how to use .asCurl to create a line of Curl from a swagger method (do you have an example?)

Answer (score 2):

The last version of swagger-ui dist bundle will show the curl commands section by default, no single change in your specification is necessary.

Comment: In addition,  one can copy-paste the full curl command from that section to a terminal or command prompt.